# Embed Salesforce.com in an iframe on some public website

Tags: iframe

I want to add my Salesforce production org on my website as an iframe. I tried this but shows error refused to display...X-Frame option deny.

Is there any way to embed my Salesforce org on a website as an iframe or my site URL shouldn't change while users can use salesforce?

Comment: I do not believe you will be able to do so as you have found SF explicitly denys framing itself. But, lets see what others have to say

Comment: I doubt you can do that. Salesforce does not allow this because of clickjack protection unless you want to disable it which is not recommended approach and you may face other challenges as mentioned in this post - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BRJIA2

Comment: What part of you site do you want to iframe? The whole thing, or just a subsection of public data? For the latter you could use a public Site, which can be iframed.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I want to show the home page of my SF Production Org. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to embed a public salesforce site on a website outside of the salesforce domain, you can disable the described problem by enabling framing settings for your site. If you want to embed the whole developer platform, you are probably out of luck.

**Allow Site iFrame embedding:**
To be able to embed a salesforce Site in an iFrame outside of salesforece domain, you need to disable the "clickjack protection" in your site settings. Shown here in the screenshot.
[image: Site settings - allow framing by any page]